# Windows Defender Firewall Blocking Ping

Tags: windows, ping, windows-firewall, windows-defender

My workstations use Windows Defender Firewall managed by local group policy. Every time I try to ping from this one workstation I receive "General Failure". When I turn the firewall off I can ping just fine so that pinpoints my issue.

I have allowed all "File and Printer Sharing" predefined rules with no luck. I then allowed all "File and Printer Sharing" rules under Advanced Firewall settings in Control Panel and that allowed me to ping.

The workstation sat over the weekend and is now back to giving me "General Failure" when I try to ping. I have verified that the "File and Printer Sharing" rules are still enabled.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of IPv4, you need to enable the following firewall rules:it's IP4 in a private network):

1. `Core Networking Diagnostics - ICMP Echo Request (ICMPv4-In)`
2. `File and Printer Sharing - ICMP Echo Request (ICMPv4-In)`

Activating either of those rules should allow ping requests to go through.

There is a difference between the two settings, although not in their effect.

I note that disabling File and Printer Sharing in Windows will
also disable the firewall rule of
"File and Printer Sharing - ICMP Echo Request (ICMPv4-In)"
and so disables PING.

If you want PING to be allowed no matter if File and Printer Sharing is
enabled or not, you should enable
"Core Networking Diagnostics - ICMP Echo Request (ICMPv4-In)".